# How to read variables from text file in ArcMap Add-in application

Tags: c#, add-in, arcmap

I have a little add-in application for ArcMap 10.6. The purpose of the app is to open a web map application in the same position where it was clicked on the ArcMap. The application works as aspected with the hardcoded parameters for the HTTP request. My question is how to do that user could define the parameters by himself? For instance to have some external text file where the user could define the parameters and my add-in could read it from there.
I have tried to simply read the text file as follows:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\ArcMapConfig.txt");
```

however, I can't access the values of lines:

```
string username = lines[1];
```

I get the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field method or property".

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where do you initiallize the the string[] lines? Where do you access the lines? Can you show it in your post?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that I do the work inside the class body public class

```
 Connector : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Tool
    {
      string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\ArcMapConfig.txt");

    }
```

The solution to my problem is very simple. I have changed `string username = lines[1];` to `string username = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\ArcMapConfig.txt")[1];`
Now I can access the parameter values from the text file. If the user will update the file it needs to reopen the ArcMap application and new values will be used. No need for reinstalling the add-in.

Comment: Or: do this processing in the constructor of this class, instead of a field initializer